# Plotting date in Pandas independent of year

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains orders, and the day each order took place, allowing multiple orders per day.  I've managed to plot the number of orders by day in dataframe df with:

```
df.groupby('order_date')['order_id'].count().plot()
```

This runs over several years, and what i'm interested in is plotting each year over top of each other, so that the x-axis consists of only a month and a day. My current attempt looks like this:

```
grouped=df.groupby([df['order_date'].map(lambda x: x.year)])
groups=[]
for name,group in grouped:
    groups.append(group)
for group in groups:
    group.groupby([group['order_date'].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x.month)+"-"+str(x.day), format="%m-%d"))])['order_id'].count().plot()
```

I group all my data by the year, then for each year I group it by a Month-Day datetime determined from its actual datetime in order_date.  However, this gives me the following error:

```
 ValueError: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-09-01 00:00:00
```

This I assume is one of my values, but I'm unsure whats actually wrong here.  Is there a simpler way to do what I want, or am I making a mistake in my code?

Comment: Can we get a minimal and a copy/paste-able portion of your data to generate a dataframe that raises the error?

Comment: I wish I could, but I cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to plot each year over top of each other, the xaxis must have the same date range. To support leap year, you can shift all date to year 2000, here is my try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

### create sample data
date = pd.date_range("2010-01-01", periods=365*3)
date = pd.Index(np.random.choice(date, 30000))
order_id = np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=30000)

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":date, "order_id":order_id})

### group by year and date
date = pd.Index(df["date"])
df2 = df["order_id"].groupby([date.year, date]).count()

### shift all year to 2000
date = df2.index.get_level_values(1)
new_date = pd.Index(pd.io.date_converters.parse_date_fields(np.ones(len(date))*2000, date.month, date.day))
year = df2.index.get_level_values(0)
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([year, new_date])

### plot
p = df2.unstack(0).plot()
p.xaxis.set_ticklabels(range(1, 13));
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I'm working on implementing this solution now.  I had the same idea you did for using one year, but I thought there might be some natural implementation for this type of plot.